# How to login Ubuntu server when network goes down (NIS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

#### Problem

I configured `/etc/network/interfaces` wrongly so that I cannot access the server.
The problem is that the server is using NIS and NFS which needs a network, and which means it cannot fetch any user information from the master server or mount the file system. 
I can boot server or use usb port or whatever. I can physically use the server machine.

#### Question

Is there any way to access to the server? Should I reinstall the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

Okay, I've got an answer. If you can use a physical machine, you can access to the shell as the root through "ubuntu recovery mode" which shows up while booting on the grub.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into single user mode as root from GRUB and correct your config.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub